# Deviation between datasheet ESL and actual measurements

Tags: decoupling-capacitor, mlcc

Optimizing a PDN, I am trying to arrive at a result that is as accurate as possible. Murata specifies the following ESL for a generic 0805 MLCC (Figure), but comparing this to the measurements presented in the AVX paper below shows orders of magnitude in difference, i.e. 10pH vs 1nH.

Any advice on how to arrive at an estimate which is as accurate as possible? I suppose I should also take into consideration the total loop inductance, particularly on bulks located further away from the IC.

Thanks!

[image: GRM21BR60J107ME15]

[AVX Induction paper](https://www.avx.com/docs/techinfo/CeramicCapacitors/parasitc.pdf)

[Loop Inductance](https://interferencetechnology.com/understanding-inductance-real-world/)

Comment: 0802 is a new one on me (unless it is an array).

Comment: Now corrected to 0805

Comment: PDN? What's that?

Comment: @winny Power Distribution Network.

Comment: @JohnD The supply planes on a PCB?

Comment: @winny Typically the way I have seen it used is an extraction of the parasitics of the PCB from the main supply/input to each of the point of load converters and loads, sometimes with passive component parasitics as well.

Comment: @JohnD Never heard of. Learned something today.

Comment: You're looking at a difference of about 3:1, not orders of magnitude.  At these values, this could be the difference in how the device is attached for measurement.

Comment: Suppose that's a translation error on my part. 1nano isn't 2 powers-of-ten orders of magnitude larger than 10pico?
Either way, the loop inductance article I attached specifies similar values far away from 10 pico where a small loop is considered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual inductance of a ceramic capacitor varies a bit across frequency (due to internal molecular alignment I understand).

The typical ESL you show from Murata looks awfully optimistic for an 0805 device; I just went to TDK (where these is a really nice selector and graph generator) and selected a [100nF 0805 part](https://product.tdk.com/en/search/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/info?part_no=C2012X7R2A104K125AA) to get the graph of (in particular) Z.

By finding the self resonance (at about 15.8MHz) I calculate that the ESL is just about exactly 1nH at that frequency and will not vary very much (perhaps 10% or so).

In my experience using a lot of different parts, the typical ESL (at any decent frequency of interest) is:

0402: about 680pH

0603: about 850pH

0805: about 1nH

1206: about 1.2nH

1210: about 1nH

The [reverse geometry parts](https://product.tdk.com/info/en/products/capacitor/ceramic/mlcc/technote/tpo/tpo00009.html) have lower ESL due to a shorter path through the device.

Note that the values above are *approximate* and will vary under environmental conditions and even capacitor ageing; an accurate model simply does not exist (and also depends on the specific manufacturer for materials and process).

It is also of interest to note that the tests done by AVX were *well* above self-resonance and the lowest frequency shown on the graphs are 1MHz.

For track inductance, my experience is that a 4 thou (100 micron) track 4 thou above a plane is about 5nH / inch.